# Разделить переменную на две равные части

Tags: r

У меня в наборе данных есть переменная возраст. Как мне создать новую факторную переменную, делящую дата сет приблизительно на 2 равные части? Заране благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `cut` позволяет указать количество частей, на которые требуется разбить исходную количественную переменную.

Пример кода:

```r
DF <- data.frame(
  group = sample(letters, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
  age = sample(18:75, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
)
DF$age_group <- cut(DF$age, breaks = 2)
```

В результате получаем данные такого вида:

```r
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ group    : Factor w/ 26 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 11 21 2 26 16 25 1 8 23 24 ...
 $ age      : int  56 49 38 50 61 34 68 26 58 33 ...
 $ age_group: Factor w/ 2 levels "(17.9,46.5]",..: 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
```

Проверим результат разбивки:

```r
> table(DF$age_group)

(17.9,46.5] (46.5,75.1] 
         48          52
```

Comment: Артем, у меня после выполнения данного кода, в панели Environment , пропадает значок свернуть - развернуть данные (синий кружочек с треугольником), сам дата фрейм сворачивается и нет визуального контроля над переменными в df, я не знаю, что с эти делать? Поэтому и обратился за помощью к сообществу. В основном это происходит при создании новой переменной факторного типа. Помогите пожалуйста советом!!!

Comment: @Gennady_F если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы